# What is renormalization?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

What is [renormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization)?

I would  want a rough description before I go and work on it properly (I did a course on QFT and on SM (which was 3rd course in the series) but skipped the 2nd course which was on Renormalization.

Comment: This is super duper broad but I do hope someone can give an example of renormalization which is not clouded by the complexities and particulars of any one physical system. Remember: ideas which appear complex because they are first introduced in advanced courses are frequently not complex themselves.

Comment: This is definitely *too broad*. @DanielSank: (and also for OP) I think [Arnold Neumaier's notes](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~neum/ms/ren.pdf) are a nice overview of what renormalization is/means *without* jumping into talking about divergent diagrams in QFT and whatnot.